# elasticsearch autocomplete for title text

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete, typeahead

I am trying to implement a auto complete suggester for movies(title) somewhat similar to IMDB. Below is mapping that i used.This mapping gives decent results. I am using edge Ngam.. are there any better alternatives?

But it has some flaws like.

"war civil" "civil war" gives same results. ie it doesn't give priority to movies with words in same order as query.

It doesn't give any results when space is omitted between words eg "smoking barrels" gives good results. but "smokingbarrels" gives zero result.

What is wrong with query and mapping below?

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/movieindex" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {},
        "analyzer": {
          "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
          },
          "edge_ngram_search_analyzer": {
            "tokenizer": "lowercase"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "edge_ngram_tokenizer": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 2,
            "max_gram": 10,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit",
              "symbol"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "movies": {
      "properties": {
        "title": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "edgengram": {
              "type": "text",
              "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer",
              "search_analyzer": "edge_ngram_search_analyzer"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


GET /movieindex/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "title.edgengram": {
              "query": "smokingbarrels",
              "fuzziness": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One hack would be to use character replacement filter to remove all spaces then just use the edge ngram

Comment: @sramalingam24 checking this out. Will get back asap.